# A js function not called in android device and called in chrome browser

Tags: android, cordova

In my phonegap application, I have welcome.html page, in this page, I included :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.37:8080/scripts/myJs.js"></script>
```

Then I call a function '**myFunction**' from myJs.js

I build the app using cordova:

```
   cordova build android
```

Then I run it on my device:

```
cordova run android
```

Debugging my app with DDMS:
I had this error:

```
uncaught ReferenceError myFunction : is not defined
```

I tried to open welcome.html on chrome browser, the function 'myFunction' is called without problems.

I can't catch the error ! a cross origin problem?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you see any 404 error or any network error?

Comment: @Harish Kommuri , no !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these plugins:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

already I have these plugins:

```
org.apache.cordova.camera
add org.apache.cordova.file
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
org.apache.cordova.device
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```